# Please recommend a CMS framework in Java good for making a monitoring system

Tags: java, frameworks, content-management-system

I already have Java code to display and process data from a database. I would now like to implement the code as modules, and incorporate as a whole into a CMS system.

EDIT2: Most important, the CMS must have good support manually written gadgets and place them using AJAX, and inter-communication between gadgets

The CMS MUST support Spring, Hibernate, etc.
The CMS MUST not be GPL, and preferably open source (lGPL, BSD,etc).
The CMS MUST have good documentation and support
The CMS MUST be secure (safe from XSS and injection) and support different levels of authorizations, (built-in or module)
The CMS MUST have good navigation and tab, (built-in or module)

+1, for having a good ajax paginated table module to display data
+1, for using ajax to change pages with support for bookmarks and history.back()
+1, for using jquery or prototype
+1, for being easy to deploy, and easy to add modules
+1, for supporting dynamically add/remove and drag-dropping of modules

Please recommend a CMS best for the job. Thank you!

EDIT: I don't need blogs or wikis or etc. I just want a framework where I can display paginated lists and time series graphs and log files. I will also host some pages for configuration. All of these code are already implemented.

EDIT2: google's api for gadgets doesn't suit me. there are many problems to this:

1. no communication between gadgets
2. no communication between gadget and
   its container
3. it's using iframe instead of ajax

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at dotCMS for your requirements

http://www.dotcms.org/

Comment: +1 for the link, I went to dotCMS and found www.jaspersoft.com/jasperreports which is terribly helpful

Comment: I'm choosing yours as the answer, although it is still not what I want, but is closest to my requirements.

Answer (score 4):

My recommendation would be [**eXo Platform**](http://www.exoplatform.com/portal/public/website/):

- It is built on Spring and Hibernate that you can [leverage](http://wiki.exoplatform.com/xwiki/bin/view/Core/Hibernate+Service).
- It is [licensed](http://www.exoplatform.com/portal/public/website/product/licensing) under Affero GPL.
- It has good [documentation](http://wiki.exoplatform.com/xwiki/bin/view/Main/WebHome) and [support](http://exoplatform.com/portal/public/website/services/support) (it's a great product).
- It is secure (it's a professional product) and has an [Organization Service](http://wiki.exoplatform.com/xwiki/bin/view/Core/Organization+Service) for personalization and authorizations.

Comment: Do I need to go open-source if I use this? Especially if I am adding modules on this

Comment: Do I need to go open-source if I use this? _**YES**_, even if you do not distribute it but use it for your own.

Comment: @TiansHUo Regarding the GPL licensing of the eXo applications, that applies only to software distribution. If you **do** distribute your code that extends code based on GPL then you will have to license your code to GPL.

Comment: yes I know that, and we DO need to distribute our program. you see, we are designing a system monitor that lists and charts collected data, but we would really like to avoid writing ui framework code like navigation and user authentication

Comment: @TiansHUo Actually, my answer was more targeted at henchman :) Anyway, now that I understand better your need, if you use more than the portlet API, you would have to contact eXo for a custom license that would allow you to distribute eXo with your application without opening your code. You may have to pay for that though. Contact them (and maybe have a look at this old thread http://www.theserverside.com/news/thread.tss?thread_id=21461).

Answer (score 4):

[Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com/) will be the definite winner. Check it out.

Comment: I've checked it out, this is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Since Alfesco is not an option I assume [Mangolia](http://www.magnolia-cms.com/home.html)  isn't either (due to license).
You requirement catalog is demanding and I'm afraid there is no out of the box CMS you can simply plugin.

Two years ago I build myself a tailored CMS using JSF and richfaces within two months using [jackrabbit](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/) JCR (JSR 170). With this approach I only needed to write glue code and caching for prerendered html-fragments for what I used apaches [velocity](http://velocity.apache.org/).

Comment: Then is there any out of the box CMS in other languages that might fit my requirements?

Comment: @TiansHUo In the PHP world they have many CMS but if you rely on java and cannot use Alfresco,eXo and Magnolia I would say no. Make or buy, sorry.

Comment: @TiansHUo Found antoher one, but didn't check against your requirements:http://www.opencms.org/en/

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Java

Answer (score 0):

Not an easy way and expansive one - oracle ECM 10g. Flexible enough and robust.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this will work for you but [JMX](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/core/mntr-mgmt/javamanagement/) is very flexible